# FormatException: Invalid envelope in flutter Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to call firebase functions from my flutter application for saving an image in firestore.

I am using the following code to upload my image data, But i'm receiving the error `FormatException: Invalid envelope`

```
_image = image.readAsBytes();
CloudFunctions.instance.call(
    functionName: 'updateUserImg',
    parameters: <String, dynamic>{
      'img':_image,
    },
  );
```

My cloud function is not even getting called, seems like i'm sending the data in wrong format.

How I can fix this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when your request times out. Make sure you have an active internet connection. In case of using an emulator over LAN, make sure you specify origin as follows.

```
cloudFunctions.useFunctionsEmulator(
        origin: "http://192.168.31.107:5001");
```

instead of

```
_cloudFunctions.useFunctionsEmulator(
        origin: "192.168.31.107:5001");
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue generally comes when your device (Emulator or Mobile) is not having an internet connection.

1. Make sure your **laptop/PC** is connected with Wifi i.e. it is having an **active internet connection**.
2. Make sure your **emulator/device** has the Wifi and/or Mobile data **ON**.

Update: (24th May)

1. Sometimes, if I switch to a different Wifi/Internet connection , then emulator shows this error. The solution to this is after switching to different Wifi/Internet connection, cold boot your emulator, when you start debugging.

Note: This option is shown when all emulators are closed and you click on `Run --> Start Debugging` on Visual Studio
[image]